# How to find the period of an arbitrary mathematical function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

Is there a function to find the period of an arbitrary (possibly complex) function in *Mathematica*?

Comment: [FourierTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FourierTransform.html)?

Comment: Please see here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16234/4764  An important question is: do you have the analytic form of the function, or do you have have it sampled in a number of points (i.e. you have some numerical data)?  If you have numerical data, are the data points equally spaces in time or not?

Comment: You might find this paper of some use. Symmetry, Anti-Symmetry, Periodicity, are all
discussed. http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/symmetry.pdf

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can check out this one. I don't know how well it works

```
Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[E^(I 2 Pi t) + Cos[3/9 Pi  t], t]

6
```

Perhaps you are also interested in the other functions in that context. Check

```
Names["Periodic`*"]
```

**EDIT**

As @Artes notes in the comments, in v10 there's a documented version of this function called `FunctionPeriod`

Comment: Works nicely for `Sech[t]`, `t - Floor[t]`, `(-1)^Floor[t]`, and (surprisingly) `JacobiDN[t, 1/3]` and `EllipticTheta[3, t, 1/2]`, but fails for `WeierstrassPPrime[t, {2, 3}]`. Clearly the thing is still under development, but it's getting there.

Comment: Another possible weakness of the function is that it does not always return the minimal period. `Sin[3t] Sin[5t]` is $\pi$-periodic, but the function returns a period of $2\pi$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha has the function "period". To what it is rendered when Mathematica kernel is called?

Comment: I also wonder how to make it return non-number values for non-periodic function.

Comment: @J.M For Sin[3x] it returns 2Pi/3 for me.

Comment: @Anixx: nothing wrong with that... it's when you're dealing with products of trigonometric functions that things get slightly hairy.

Comment: @Anixx, you could do that with something like `p = If[Periodic\`PeriodicFunctionQ[##], Periodic\`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[##], Infinity] &;`, so `p[Sin[2 Pi t] Sin[t], t]` returns `Infinity`

Comment: @J.M. Why Wolfram Alpha returns the correct period for Sin[3t] Sin[5t]? What function does it use?

Comment: @Anixx, you can always use wolframalpha, `getPeriod[exp_] := 
 WolframAlpha[
   "period of " <> 
    ToString[exp], {{"Periodicities:MathematicalFunctionIdentityData",
      1}, "ComputableData"}][[1, -1, -1]]`

Comment: LOL I think wolfram Alpha uses Mathematica kernel to get the result.

Comment: @Anixx, yes, but it's not open source. Perhaps the answer's function has been improved for the next version, or who konws

Comment: If you first apply any of `TrigReduce`, `TrigFactor`, or `TrigExpand` to `Sin[3t]Sin[5t]`, you get the correct result.  Strangely, if you apply `TrigToExp`, you get $-\pi$.

Comment: I tried the following: D[First[a /. 
   Solve[Refine[Reduce[{f[x + a] == f[x]}, a], 
     C[1] \[Element] Integers], a]], C[1]] It works sometimes. Can anybody improve?

Comment: The function doesn't work with complex exponentials.

Comment: @CHM, isn't E^(I 2 Pi t) a complex exponential? Which do you mean?

Comment: @Rojo this doesn't work for me: **Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[(1/2) (Exp[1.5 I t] + Exp[-1.5 I t]),t]**

Comment: @Rojo Go figure, **Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[(1/2) (Exp[3 ( I t)/2] + 
    Exp[-3 ( I t)/2]), t]** evaluates to -4Pi/3. Weird.

Comment: @Rojo In _ver. 10_ there is `FunctionPeriod` however I couldn't find its advantages over `Periodic'PeriodicFunctionPeriod`, at least such that I'd like to mention them. In all the above examples where the latter fails either the former does.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a numeric approximation method that can be useful when no analytic information is known. I will illustrate with the function **WeierstrassPPrime[t, {2, 3}]** that was mentioned in a comment to one response.

We begin by taking random steps, and sampling the function at those steps (I'll explain the random step size presently). We then plot the coordinates thus obtained, to do a visual check that we have at least a few periods.

```
SeedRandom[111222333];
xvals = Accumulate[RandomReal[.01, 3000]];
xyvals = Chop[Table[{t, WeierstrassPPrime[t, {2, 3}]}, {t, xvals}]];

ListPlot[xyvals]
```

[image]

So far so good. We now order these by their y coordinates, and subtract *x* values that correspond to neighboring *y* values.

```
sortd = xyvals[[Ordering[xyvals[[All, 2]]]]];
xdiffs = Differences[sortd[[All, 1]]];
```

Of course the neighboring *y* values might not be terribly close. I will use the following heuristic to "order" them in terms of which corresponding *x* differences I want to use. We take each *y* difference, and divide by the sqrt of sum of squares of the two *y* values from which it arises. We regard *x* differences as being more useful when that ratio is smaller. The idea here is that if the *y* difference is zero then, for this function (which is monotonic on a period), we are "close" to an integral number of periods apart in corresponding *x* values.

```
ydiffs = Abs[Differences[sortd[[All, 2]]]];
ynorms = Map[Norm, Partition[sortd[[All, 2]], 2, 1]];
weighteddiffs = ydiffs/ynorms;
```

So we now sort according to the heuristic described above.

```
sortdxdiffs = Abs[xdiffs[[Ordering[weighteddiffs]]]];
```

Next we discard those *x* differences that are (approximately) **zero** periods apart.

```
usediffs1 = 
  Select[sortdxdiffs[[1 ;; 500]], # >= Max[sortdxdiffs]/10 &];
```

From these we can cull the differences that are approximately **one** (as opposed to more) period apart.

```
usediffs = Select[usediffs1, # <= 1.5*Min[usediffs1] &];
```

Finally we average these. This gives a fairly good approximation to a period.

```
In[237]:= Mean[Abs[usediffs]]

Out[237]= 2.39443
```

So we have an approximate period of 2.3944 or so.

I will now mention why we did not take regular spacing: had we done so, we would require at least an order of magnitude more points to get an approximation this good; best we might get from points spaced at intervals of .001 is an approximation to that many places. While I do not claim our averaging approximation to be perfect, I will surmise it is good to at least three or so places.

One might use the differences that are multiple periods apart to get a possibly better estimate via weighted averaging (the idea being that more samples giving a lower variance). I'm just showing a simple computation requiring minimal work to get an average.

There are (at least) two problems with this approach. One is that we used real data, whereas the request was to handle complex periodic functions. It is not too difficult to extend to complex. One might work with real and imaginary parts separately, for example, and either average or use the lesser if one is roughly an integral multiple of the other.

A bigger problem is that we relied on monotonicity within periods in order to assert that coordinates with approximately equal *y* values had *x* values that differ by roughly an integer number of periods. Provided there are no flat parts (e.g. from a Haar wavelet), one can often deduce which *x* differences correspond to period separations by clumping them. The ones that are an integral number of periods apart will tend to be more common than differences that come from close *y* values where corresponding *x* pairs were not separated by an integral number of periods. This idea at least works for functions that are, to crude approximation, roughly sinusoidal. I'm sure there are more pathological examples where it will fail. In such cases some plotting and human intervention might be needed in order to figure out which *x* differences correspond to actual period separations and which come from inadvertent closeness of corresponding *y* values.

This process can be much harder for experimental data. For an example of such, see [this cepheid demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CepheidVariableStarLightCurveAnalysis/) or [this related pulsar star period demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RadialVelocityCurveFitting/)
How to handle such a problem is another topic for another day.

--- edit ---

Here is an example of how one might deal with nonmonotonicity. I will use a function mentioned in the comments.

```
func[x_] := WeierstrassP[x, {2, 3}]
```

Again we will take a large number of samples. Some experimenting indicated what would be a good set. I'll show the plot as well.

```
SeedRandom[111222333];
xvals = Accumulate[RandomReal[.001, 10000]];
xyvals = Chop[Table[{t, Chop[func[t]]}, {t, xvals}]];

ListPlot[xyvals]
```

[image]

Again we create differences of *x* coordinates that correspond to neighboring *y* values. This time I'll be less fussy and use all of them, excluding ones that are quite small

```
sortd = xyvals[[Ordering[xyvals[[All, 2]]]]];
xdiffs = Differences[sortd[[All, 1]]];
sortdxdiffs = Sort[Select[Abs[xdiffs], # >= .1 &]];
```

Here is where the clumping happens. We will split this list, grouping pairs that are within .001 of one another. I'll explain why in a moment.

```
collected = Split[sortdxdiffs, #2 - #1 <= .001 &];


In[211]:= collected // Length

Out[211]= 1606
```

Now we look at the lengths of these groupings. One will stand out as being huge relative to the rest. This is the "main clump" (apologies for use of technical jargon).

```
lens = Map[Length, collected];
Table[RankedMax[lens, k], {k, 1, 5}]

Out[231]= {2800, 169, 45, 30, 29}
```

We take this clump and average its members. This gives our estimate for the period.

```
mainclump = First[Select[collected, Length[#] > 2000 &]];
Mean[mainclump]

Out[233]= 2.39443
```

So why does this grouping tactic work? The idea is that for a curve like this, it is roughly a 50-50 proposition whether *y* neighbors will belong to *x* neighbors that are roughly a period apart vs. on the flip side of the same period. In the latter case the *x* distances are spread out over a wide range, whereas the (approximately) period-separated *x* distances will aggregate near the period. As nearly half fall into that class, we go for that large set. Hence the terminology of "clumping".

The 50-50 above is loose talk. Since *y* neighbors can come from actual *x* neighbors, and since we do not have as many full periods as mirrored pairs of half periods, it is more like a bit under one in three that we get full period separation of *x* values for neighboring *y* pairs. But so what? We still get our clump. Had we used more periods, tehre would be other clumps of integral period separation, and we could use those as well in the averaging process, of course weighting by the appropriate integer for each.

--- end edit ---

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Real programmers don't define all their variables.

Comment: Nice. Comparing the result of the approximate method with the result of `N[2 WeierstrassHalfPeriods[{2, 3}]][[1]] // Chop` shows that the algorithm returns pretty good estimates. I wonder if this can be extended to find the other period? However, if we look at the function `WeierstrassP` instead of `WeierstrassPPrime`, the method here does not do so well, because as already said, the current method relies on monotonicity within a single period.

Comment: For another example of a function where the method in this answer does not perform so well, try the Dixon elliptic function `6 WeierstrassP[x, {0, 1/27}]/(1 - 3 WeierstrassPPrime[x, {0, 1/27}])`, whose real period is `Beta[1/3, 1/3]/3`; it is monotonic within a single period, but has a flat section.

Comment: I tried that example. It appears to have a period of **Beta[1/3, 1/3]**, or around 5.29992. My method gave 5.2998. If I make use of more of the data I get 5.999. These are, suffice it to say, quite close to the mark.

Comment: @J.M. WeierstrassP is a harder case. I'll show how to handle that in an edit. It will show what I had meant by "clumping".

Comment: Whoops, it seems I copied down the period of the Dixon elliptic function wrong from my notes; your method does pretty well on it, indeed. Sorry for the needless worry.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, are you aware of methods to partition a finite `Integer` sequence into its pre-period and its period (either of which could be empty?). Eg, trajectory of 5 in the 3x+1 problem would give pre-period {5,16,8} and period {4,2,1}

Comment: @alancalvitti Not sure what might be a reliable method offhand. This might work (have not tested for reliability though). Requires several repeats of the periodic part. `periodicity[seq_] := Module[
  {len = Length[seq], dft = Rest[Abs[Fourier[seq]]], pos},
  pos = Position[dft, Max[dft]];
  Round[len/pos[[1, 1]]]
  ]` This gives the period length. Now work from that. (Probably you should pose this as a separate question so you can get different approaches.)

Comment: One might use `Median[Abs[usediffs]]` instead of `Mean[Abs[usediffs]]`. In some cases this improves the accuracy significantly.

Answer (score 7):

My earlier post, directing people to a paper, seems to have been relegated to a comment on some other marginally-related post,  so I will try to explain in-line enough of why the answer to the question is related to symmetry, and what one might in fact use a computer algebra system to do about it. I suppose it is possible to copy the whole paper into stackexchange, but is that really useful?

Here's an except from the paper..

Consider symmetry as invariance under a group of transformations.  Thus, given a transformation $T$ that maps some domain
$R$ to itself, we say that $f: ~R\rightarrow R$ is symmetric under $T$
if and only if $f = T[f]$. Analyzing the set of **all** possible $T$
in full generality is neither practical nor particularly helpful.
Instead, let us focus on transformations $T$ that can be expressed in
a particular, but still interesting, form. Given $f(x)$, define
$T[f](x)$ as a combination of linear transforms around the function
$f$ as follows:
$$
  T_{a, b, c, d}[f](x) = a * f( b * x + c) + d;
$$
Such a family of transformations is parameterized by 4 constants. For
our current discussion you may assume they are real numbers
$\{a,~b,~c,~d\}$, though this could be generalized.  The family of
transformations is fairly powerful; in particular, it allows us to
express the forms previously mentioned plus other traditional notions
of symmetry. Thus the notion that a function $f$ is even simply means
that it is invariant under $T_{1, -1, 0, 0}$. Similarly, the notion
that a function is odd simply means that it is invariant under $T_{-1,
-1, 0, 0}$. This family of transformations also allows us to express
periodicity, since a function periodic with period $p$ will be
invariant under $T_{1, 0, p, 0}$.*

..........

A solution to this problem can be expressed as a call to Reduce in Mathematica, though exactly what Reduce will do depends on the version of Mathematica, past, present, and future. The paper was written in 2004.
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/symmetry.pdf

and no, it does not mention Fourier series, which is an alternative but rather unrelated approach to determining periodicity.

Comment: Hello Richard, I was the one that "relegated" your previous post to a comment, but not to a "marginally-related post"... rather, I converted it to a comment on the very post that you answered (so surely must be related, right?)! I was responding to flags from other knowledgable users that your post was insufficient to _stand alone as an answer as per the site's standards_ and was more appropriate as a comment. The excerpt is a good start, but as Artes suggested earlier, some _Mathematica_ code demonstrating it would be helpful to the user and the reader.

Comment: I'll admit, I know nothing of this topic to judge whether your statement that "A solution to this problem can be expressed as a call to Reduce in Mathematica,..." is sufficient for the reader, but perhaps someone else can weigh in on that.

Comment: I suppose that one could examine the (rather complicated) output of `Reduce[Sin[x + a] == Sin[x], x]` and discover an `a==2Pi*C[1]` near the end.  It's really incumbent upon Richard to provide the example he suggests.

Comment: Generally, it's fine to provide pointers to papers but, if that's *all* and "answer" does, then a comment is really more appropriate. Also, the comment was placed under the original question. If that's genuinely a "marginally-related post", then why are you posting an answer at all?

Comment: I'm new to Stack Exchange; the way I parsed the headers it seemed to me that the earlier comment was stuck under "FourierTransform".   Apologies (since I guess I misunderstood).  Your comment about using Reduce is the most direct method, and if Reduce can't solve that problem, perhaps the correct approach is to make Reduce better. There is another approach which is to implement a calculus of those transformations which allows you (sometimes) to infer T[...] from the T[...] of constituents. e.g. sum of periodic functions with same period is also periodic etc. Specific code in cited term paper.

Comment: @RichardFateman There is an [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help). Among other things, you'll learn that you can [create new tags after you have 300 rep](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and how to [format your posts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

I found another method:

```
Period[f_, t_] := 
 D[First[a /. 
    Solve[Refine[
      Reduce[{Function[t, f][x + a] == Function[t, f][x]}, a], 
      C[1] \[Element] Integers], a]], C[1]]
Period[Cos[3 x], x]
```

But it seems it works only for basic functions.