# Highlighting a single Period of a Trig Plot

Tags: plotting, trigonometry

How do I highlight a single period of a trig function say by using color and/or thickness when the graph itself extends further than just a single period? 
Thanks...Gregory Lane

Comment: Just plot a trig function two times, use different styles and ranges (PlotStyle and PlotRange, respectively). To combine two plots use Show function.

Answer (score 11):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, Mesh -> {{0, 2 Pi}}, 
 MeshShading -> {ColorData[1][1], Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**

*[@belisarius pointed out that another answer shows the built-in, but undocumented, function `` Period`PeriodicFunctionPeriod `` that returns the period of a periodic function with exact coefficients.]*

If you'd like more general functionality, one can write a function to get the period and another to highlight a period from an arbitrary starting point.  The pattern in `getPeriod` parses the typical affine transformations of trigonometric graphs studied in school.

```
ClearAll[highlightPeriod, getPeriod];
SetAttributes[highlightPeriod, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[getPeriod, HoldAll];

getPeriod[f_, var_] := 
  Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[Rationalize[f, 0], var];

highlightPeriod[f_, dom_, x0_: 0., opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
  Block @@
   Join[
    Hold[{dom}] /. {x_, __} :> x,
    Hold[
     Plot[f, dom, Mesh -> {{x0, x0 + getPeriod[f, First@dom]}}, 
      MeshShading -> (OptionValue[MeshShading] /. 
         None -> {ColorData[1][1], Red}), opts]
     ]
    ];
```

The real key is the two lines of the `Plot` command.  The function definition could consist of just these two lines, but there's a risk.  The use of `Block` is to keep the function and variable in the domain `dom` from evaluating before being passed to `Plot`.  Without this, if `x` has been set to a numerical value, then its value and not the symbol would be passed to `Plot`, which would not work since a number cannot serve as a variable.

Calling `highlightPeriod` is like calling `Plot`, except there is an option third argument `x0` that specifies the starting point of the highlighted period.

Examples:

```
ex1 = highlightPeriod[Cot[x/2], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}];
ex2 = highlightPeriod[Cot[x/2], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, Pi,
   MeshShading -> {Purple, Orange},  (* change color *)
   MeshStyle -> None,                (* removes mesh dots *)
   PlotStyle -> Thick];
ex3 = highlightPeriod[2 Cos[1.2 x + 0.5] - 0.7, {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}];
ex4 = With[{f = 2 Cos[1.2 x + 0.5] - 0.7},
   highlightPeriod[f, {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
    x /. FindRoot[f, {x, 0.}]]       (* start at a zero of f *)
   ];

GraphicsGrid@{
  {ex1, ex2},
  {ex3, ex4}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The old `getPeriod`, for reference:

```
getPeriod[Sin|Cos|Sec|Csc]:=2Pi;
getPeriod[Tan|Cot]:=Pi;
getPeriod[(amp_:1.) f_[(a_:1.) \
x_Symbol+b_:0]+vshift_:0.]/;NumericQ[a]:=getPeriod[f]/a;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use the answers here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5852/193

Comment: @belisarius Thanks.  I hadn't seen that one.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way:

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}], 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]]]
```

If you want to add interactivity,  you can translate the red cycle to the right one cycle (or whatever you choose):

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}], 
  Plot[Sin[x - j], {x, j, 2 Pi + j}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]]], {j, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]