# What's wrong in FunctionPeriod?

Tags: periodic-function

```
FunctionPeriod[Sin[16 Pi x/5 - Pi/8], x, Integers]
```

> ```
> 80
> ```

then I `ListPlot` the function:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[0, 90], Sin[16/5 π Range[0, 90] - π/8]}], Filling -> Axis]
```

then I test the number:

```
Union[Simplify[Sin[16/5 π Range[0, 90] - π/8]]]
```

> ```
> {-Cos[π/40], Cos[(7 π)/40],Cos[(9 π)/40], -Sin[(3 π)/40], -Sin[π/8]}
> ```

so I wonder why *Mathematica* gives 80 instead of 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the period of an arbitrary mathematical function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/how-to-find-the-period-of-an-arbitrary-mathematical-function)

Comment: The help file for `FunctionPeriod` says it "gives a period p of the function f over the reals such that f(x+p)==f(x)". This is certainly the case here: 80 is "a period" of the function. Nowhere in the docs does it say that it will give the minimum period (in this case 5).

Comment: Oh I understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FunctionPeriod` is certainly imperfect.  There is already discussion of this in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/how-to-find-the-period-of-an-arbitrary-mathematical-function), though that predates `FunctionPeriod` and uses lower level tools buried in the `Periodic` context.  Nonetheless, the same comments apply:

```
FunctionPeriod[Sin[3 t] Sin[5 t], t]
(* Incorrect result: 2Pi *)

FunctionPeriod[TrigFactor[Sin[3 t] Sin[5 t]], t]
(* Correct result: Pi *)
```

Similarly,

```
FunctionPeriod[Sin[16 Pi x/5 - Pi/8], x, Integers]
(* Incorrect result: 80 *)

FunctionPeriod[TrigFactor[Sin[16 Pi x/5 - Pi/8]], x, Integers]
(* Correct result: 5 *)
```

I don't know of any cases where `FunctionPeriod` returns a result that is too small so you might generally try applying several of the `Trig*` commands and grab the absolute value of the minimum.

Comment: It's good to have this information in an answer rather than the comment section like the duplicate to which you refer.  Is this issue best considered a bug or functionality-in-progress?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as the other question predates `FunctionPeriod`.  Also, while `FunctionPeriod` builds on the `Periodic` context, there are differences.  I guess I'd say it's a bug but I doubt that it's a very high priority bug.

Comment: Thanks for `TrigFactor` and `Trig*` - an excellent answer

Comment: @MarkMcClure fair enough.