# How to find the minimum positive period of a function

Tags: trigonometry

Through `Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6 // TrigReduce` operation, we can know that the minimum positive period of `Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6` is `Pi/2`

But

```
Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[Sin[x]^6 + Cos[x]^6, x]
```

returns `Pi`.Refer to this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/how%20-%20to%20-%20find%20-%20the%20-%20%20%20%20period%20-%20of%20-%20an%20-%20arbitrary%20-%20mathematical%20-%20function).

How can MMA solve the minimum positive period of a function by a common method?

Comment: from help on `FunctionPeriod` it says : `gives a period` and not `minimum` period. So $\pi$ is valid period. Also comment there by JM in the link you posted says `Another possible weakness of the function is that it does not always return the minimal period` so may be one should call `TrigReduce` first and then call `FunctionPeriod` on the result. Then it does return `Pi/2` in this case. May be WRI should fix this function so it returns minimum period.