# Finding the Period of a Limit Cycle

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parametric-functions, nonlinear, periodic-function

I'm interested in the periods of limit cycles of the Wilson-Cowan equations which have the form
$$x'(t) = -x  + S(ax(t) - by(t) +e)$$
$$y'(t) = -y + S(cx(t) - dy(t) + f)$$

where $$S(x) = 1 + \frac{\tanh(\frac{x}{2})}{2}$$

You can observe a limit cycle with the parameters seen in the following code:

```
    s[x_] := (1  + Tanh[x/2]/2);

    a = 10;
    b = 10;
    c = 10;
    d = -5;
    e = -0.75;
    f = -15;

    wc = {-x + s[(a*x) - (b*y) + e], -y + s[(c*x) - (d*y) + f]};
    T = 40;
    point = {0.77, 0.29};
    LimCyc = ParametricPlot[
       Evaluate[
        First[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
          NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t] + s[(a*x[t]) - (b*y[t]) + e], 
            y'[t] == -y[t] + s[(c*x[t]) - (d*y[t]) + f], 
            Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]]], {t, 0, 
        T}, PlotStyle -> Red];

    Show[StreamPlot[wc, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
      ImageSize -> {500, 500}], LimCyc]
```

Is there an easy way to numerically compute the period of a limit cycle for a given set of parameters?[image: Limit cycle observed in Wilson-Cowan equations with parameters a = 10, b = 10, c = 10, d = -5, e = -0.75, f = -15]

Comment: Could you check your parameter values?  I don't get the same when I solve the model.  Also, is `b` supposed to be `d` in the `y'[t]` equation?  In general, folks prefer if you add your code to the question.  And, could you also provide a reference to these equations?

Comment: I made some edits! Sorry about that. Hopefully I have it right now. I'll try to clean up my code and add it soon. Here's a reference (eq. 7): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4733815/

Comment: thanks, that works now

Comment: Check [this prior MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5852/how-to-find-the-period-of-an-arbitrary-mathematical-function/5896). You would want to work with `res = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t] + s[(a*x[t]) - (b*y[t]) + e], 
    y'[t] == -y[t] + s[(c*x[t]) - (d*y[t]) + f], 
    Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, T}];
Plot[res, {t, 0, T}]` (The plot is not actually needed, it's for illustration).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although it's primarily designed for ecological models, my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/ecoevo) can help.  First, you need to install it with

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]
```

Then, load the package and define your model:

```
<< EcoEvo`;

S[z_] := 1 + Tanh[z/2]/2;

SetModel[{
  Aux[x] -> {Equation :> -x + S[a x - b y + e]},
  Aux[y] -> {Equation :> -y + S[c x - d y + f]}
}]
```

Doublecheck that it matches your results:

```
a = 10; b = 10; c = 10; d = -5; e = -0.75; f = -15;

sol = EcoSim[{x -> 0.75, y -> 0.25}, 20];

Show[
 PlotEcoStreams[{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}],
 RuleListPlot[sol, PlotStyle -> Pink]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now use the final result from the simulation as an initial guess for [`FindEcoCycle`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/FindEcoCycle.nb):

```
ec = FindEcoCycle[FinalSlice[sol]];
PlotDynamics[ec]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The period can be found as the final time of `ec`:

```
FinalTime[ec]
(* 5.27899 *)
```

As a bonus, you can calculate Floquet multipliers with [`EcoEigenvalues`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/EcoEigenvalues.nb):

```
EcoEigenvalues[ec]
(* {3.6338*10^-7, -0.71155} *)
```

If you want to avoid the package, the idea is to warm up the simulation, look for a maximum in one variable (say `x`), take a tiny step further, then use `WhenEvent` to look for when you return to that point.  There's also a Method using `FindRoot`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would the EcoEvo package also work for finding the period of a limit cycle in three dimensional model?

Comment: @Cheyne There's no limit on the number of equations, so maybe!

Comment: @Chris K, I think there has been an update so , This won't work"SetModel[{
  Aux[x] -> {Equation :> -x[t] + S[a x[t] - b y[t] + e]},
  Aux[y] -> {Equation :> -y[t] + S[c x[t] - d y[t] + f]}
}]"-- need to change to "SetModel[{
  Aux[x] -> {Equation :> -x + S[a x - b y + e]},
  Aux[y] -> {Equation :> -y + S[c x[t] - d y + f]}
}]". Thanks for "EcoEvo"

Comment: @ChrisK, Would you suggest how to implement above method if there was an explicit time dependent factor " x'[t] == -x[t] + s[(a*x[t]) - (b*y[t]) + e] " instead of this if it were " x'[t] == -x[t](1- Sin[t] Exp[-t ]) + s[(a*x[t]) - (b*y[t]) + e] ". It would be very kind of you , if you could show us how to implement your method for explicit time dependent differential equation .

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple approach to get the period of the unknown limit cycle.
The idea is to approximate the limitcycle by a circle (1st harmonic) around the mean of the limitcycle:

solution `NDSolve`

```
XY = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t] + s[(a*x[t]) - (b*y[t]) + e],y'[t] == -y[t] + s[(c*x[t]) - (d*y[t]) + f],Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}]
```

some data of the last points

```
txy = Table[ { t , Norm[ Through[XY[t]]] } , {t,Subdivide[T/2, T, 100]}];
```

Fit the circle

```
{m1, m2} = NIntegrate[Through[XY[t]], {t, T/2, T}]/(T/2);
mod = NonlinearModelFit[txy, {Norm[{m1, m2} +r {Cos[2 Pi t/T1 - \[Alpha]1], Sin[2 Pi t/T1 - \[Alpha]1]}],r > 0}, { r, T1, \[Alpha]1}, t, Method -> "NMinimize"]
mod["BestFitParameters"]
(*{r -> 0.406525, T1 -> 5.28612, \[Alpha]1 -> 2.39255}*)
```

the period of the limitcycle `T1 -> 5.28612`

check result

```
Plot[ Evaluate[Through[XY[t]]] , {t, T/2, T},GridLines ->Evaluate[{{T - T1, T}, None} /. mod["BestFitParameters"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Clever approach!

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks,  applying `Fourier` would have been much more extensive!

Answer (score 8):

I'll elaborate on the method indicated by @ChrisK involving use of `WhenEvent` to find a pair of maxima. Here I find a bunch of such pairs and take differences. It will be clear that they converge.

```
s[x_] := (1 + Tanh[x/2]/2);
{a, b, c, d, e, f} = {10, 10, 10, -5, -0.75, -15};
T = 40;
point = {0.77, 0.29};
```

We find both max and min values un `y[t]` (could also do this for `x[t]` but one suffices). THis is done by recording values `t` for which `y'[t]` vanishes.

```
extrema = 
  Reap[NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -x[t] + s[(a*x[t]) - (b*y[t]) + e], 
      y'[t] == -y[t] + s[(c*x[t]) - (d*y[t]) + f], 
      Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == point], 
      WhenEvent[y'[t] == 0, Sow[t]]}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 3 T}]][[2, 
    1]];
```

We want to go from peaks to peaks and valleys to valleys so we find time differences between extrema located two apart.

```
Differences[Partition[extrema, 2]]

(* Out[457]= {{5.38632, 5.29292}, {5.2813, 5.27931}, {5.27904, 
  5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 
  5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 
  5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 
  5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 
  5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 
  5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 5.27899}, {5.27899, 
  5.27899}} *)
```

And 5.27899 falls out as the period.

Comment: Nice simple illustration of the general idea!  Just a note that while this approach works well for this example, but as a general approach it can be tricked if there are multiple local maxima within one period.  In that case, you should first find a global maximum, then use `WhenEvent` to detect when the system returns there.

Comment: @ChrisK Right, this method was assuming that the limit cycle is convex (weaker assumptions would suffice though). I probably should have noted that.

Comment: It has its pitfalls, but it's nice whenever it works well.