# How to determine the frequency of oscillations in system of three ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, chemistry, frequency

I want to determine the frequency of oscillations in a system of three stiff ODEs ([Oregonator model](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Oregonator)). That model describes a chemical oscillator.

I have a slightly more advanced model of the default or regular Oregonator. It consists of three ODEs:

```
ode1=ε*x'[t]==x[t](1-x[t])-2*(x[t]-μ)/(x[t]+μ)*(r*α1*y[t]+q*((α2*z[t])/(1-z[t])));
ode2=ξ1*y'[t]==x[t](1+β2*z[t])-α1*y[t]-((x[t]*(1+β1*y[t]+β2*z[t]))/((1-z[t])+η*(1-y[t])))*(1-z[t]);
ode3=ξ2*z'[t]==x[t]*(1+β1*y[t])-(α2*z[t])/(1-z[t])-((x[t]*(1+β1*y[t]+β2*z[t]))/((1-z[t])+η*(1-y[t])))*η*(1-y[t]);
```

with the initial (example) conditions `ic`

```
ic2 = {x[0] == .5, y[0] == 0.1, z[0] == 0.3};
```

I use `NDSolveValue` for this:

```
{xSol, ySol, zSol} = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ic2}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

This looks like this:

[image: Oregonator system solution]

So far, so fine. I now need to determine the frequency of the oscillations in this model with three ODEs.

I found [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47917/determine-frequency-of-oscillations), but that only features a single ODE. And as I'm really a Mathematica novice, I also didn't understand how the `Reap` and `Sow` worked.

The suggested solution was as follows:

```
pts = 
 Reap[s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1, 
      WhenEvent[y'[x] == 0, Sow[x]]}, {y, y'}, {x, 0, 30}]][[2, 1]]

(* Out[290]= {0.448211158984, 4.6399193764, 7.44068279785, 10.953122261, \
13.8722260952, 17.2486864443, 20.2244048853, 23.5386505821, \
26.5478466115, 29.8261176372} *)

Plot[{Evaluate[y[x] /. s], Evaluate[y'[x] /. s]}, {x, 0, 30}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

and then finding the differences:

```
diffs = Differences[pts, 1, 2]

(* Out[288]= {6.99247163887, 6.31320288463, 6.43154329733, \
6.29556418327, 6.35217879014, 6.28996413777, 6.32344172616, \
6.28746705515} *)

Mean[diffs]

(* Out[289]= 6.41072921417 *)
```

This looks exactly what I need, but I don't know how to apply this to my three ODEs? I preferably want to keep the initial conditions, `ic`, in a separate variable like I now have.

Can anyone show me how to modify the above solution so that it works with my system? I want to determine the frequency separately for `x[t]`, `y[t]` and `z[t]`. If people have a different solution than proposed in the related question, you're of course very welcome!

Many thanks in advance!

**[Current file with all the needed variables, ODEs and my use of NDSolveValue. You can copy and modify this.](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/1c1d9200-f4a3-44fd-a39e-e68bfb8d74b5)**

Comment: Another related Q&A: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129993/using-eventlocator-to-detect-periodic-solutions-in-ndsolve

Comment: To determine the frequency of oscillatory data the FFT: Fourier is commonly used.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks! Will look into that one.

Comment: Hi @DanielHuber thanks for mentioning that! Is there a very simple beginner example in which the frequency is calculated? And some explanation about FFT?

Comment: It is not too easy if you never heard about it, but it is a standard tool in data analysis. There are zillion of articles on the web,.You may e.g. look at: https://www.earlevel.com/main/2002/08/31/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-fft/. You should play around with signals of the form Sin[f1 t]+ Sin[f2 t]+.. and see what the output of Fourier is. Note that in general the output is complex and that Fourier returns a list:  first element: zero frequency component, second: base frequency, first overtone,.. up to the highest frequency, then highest negative frequency, then the second highest,..

Comment: Oke thanks Daniel! So if I apply ~Fourier[]~ to the solution of one of the three NDSolve, I get a plot with the all the frequencies in the data and the highest peak is the most dominant frequency? Is that correct?

Comment: No, Fourier is for discrete numerical data like measurements. If you do that, try to sample an integer number of cycles. Otherwise your peaks will broaden. However, if you have a function, then you need FourierTransfom. This will return a new function that has peaks at the frequencies contained in the original function. Note that the original function is assumed to be periodic. Play with it to get a feeling for it.

Comment: Oke thanks Daniel, will do!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/ecoevo) as in [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228323/6358).

First, you need to install it with

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]
```

Then, load the package and define your model:

```
<< EcoEvo`;

SetModel[{
   Aux[x] -> {Equation :> (x[t] (1 - x[t]) - 2*(x[t] - μ)/(x[t] + μ)*(r*α1*y[t] + q*((α2*z[t])/(1 - z[t]))))/ε},
   Aux[y] -> {Equation :> (x[t] (1 + β2*z[t]) - α1*y[t] - ((x[t]*(1 + β1*y[t] + β2*z[t]))/((1 - z[t]) + η*(1 - y[t])))*(1 - z[t]))/ξ1},
   Aux[z] -> {Equation :> (x[t]*(1 + β1*y[t]) - (α2*z[t])/(1 - z[t]) - ((x[t]*(1 + β1*y[t] + β2*z[t]))/((1 - z[t]) + η*(1 - y[t])))*η*(1 - y[t]))/ξ2}
}];
```

Simulate for 40 time steps to get on the limit cycle:

```
sol = EcoSim[{x -> 0.5, y -> 0.1, z -> 0.3}, 40];
GraphicsRow[{PlotDynamics[sol, x], PlotDynamics[sol, y], PlotDynamics[sol, z]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Find the limit cycle using [`FindEcoCycle`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/ref/FindEcoCycle.nb):

```
ec = FindEcoCycle[FinalSlice[sol]];
GraphicsRow[{PlotDynamics[ec, x], PlotDynamics[ec, y], PlotDynamics[ec, z]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Make sure the initial and final values are the same:

```
InitialSlice[ec]
FinalSlice[ec]

(* {x -> 0.617907, y -> 0.522312, z -> 0.989451} *)
(* {x -> 0.617907, y -> 0.522312, z -> 0.989451} *)
```

Finally, the period can be extracted as the final time of `ec`:

```
FinalTime[ec]
(* 2.71597 *)
```

**Addendum (2/8/21):**

To answer E. Chan-López's question, to find equilibria use `SolveEcoEq`.

```
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
(* {{x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}, {x -> 0.000395349, y -> 1., z -> 1.}, {x -> 0.0279224, y -> 0.06391, z -> 0.881397}, {x -> 0.0279224, y -> 0.124848, z -> 1.08789}, {x -> 0.0279224, y -> 0.988952, z -> 1.00342}} *)
```

Apparently they're all unstable:

```
EcoStableQ[eq]
(* {False, False, False, False, False} *)
```

Comment: Hey @ChrisK thanks for your answer! I’ll try it out (at last Saturday) and let you know!

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks, it works nicely

Comment: Hi! How many equilibrium points can you calculate in your model?

Comment: @E.Chan-López I added the equilibria to my answer - looks like there are five, all of which are unstable.

Comment: @ChrisK I added a calculation to show the existence of a Hopf bifurcation at a non-trivial equilibrium point.

Answer (score 1):

Contributing to Chris's analysis:

Taking $q=\displaystyle\frac{33}{4}$, $r=\displaystyle\frac{1}{90}$, $\alpha_{1}=\displaystyle\frac{64}{33}$, $\alpha_{1}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{22}$, $\beta_{1}=24$, $\beta_{2}=3/4$, $\xi_{1}=1$, $\xi_{2}=1$, $\eta=32$, $\mu=\displaystyle\frac{16}{1517}$, and $\varepsilon$ as a free parameter, we obtain five non-trivial equilibrium points.

The system:

```
 f1 = 1/ε (x (1 - x) - 2*(x - μ)/(x + μ)*(r*α1*y + q*((α2*z)/(1 - z))));
 f2 = 1/ξ1 (x (1 + β2*z) - α1*y - ((x*(1 + β1*y + β2*z))/((1 - z) + η*(1 - y)))*(1- z));
 f3 = 1/ξ2 (x*(1 + β1*y) - (α2*z)/(1 - z) - ((x*(1 + β1*y + β2*z))/((1 - z) + η*(1 - y)))*η*(1 - y));
  F = {f1, f2, f3};
  X = {x, y, z};
```

The Jacobian matrix:

```
J = FullSimplify[D[F, {X}]];
```

The parameter values and non-trivial equilibrium points:

```
 q = 33/4; 
 r = 1/90; 
 α1 = 64/33; 
 α2 = 1/22; 
 β1 = 24; 
 β2 = 3/4; 
 ξ1 = 1; 
 ξ2 = 1;
 η = 32; 
 μ = 16/1517;

 X0 = N[Normal[Solve[F == 0 && Variables[F] > 0, X]]]
      (*{{x -> 1/2, y -> 1/4, z -> 1/4}, 
      {x -> 13.3111, y -> 12.0089, z -> 1.00458},
      {x -> 0.0105402, y -> 0.999138, z -> 1.02416}, 
      {x -> 2.38478, y -> 1.33557, z -> 1.28417}, 
      {x -> 0.0103128, y -> 0.0337578, z -> 5.68495}}*)
```

The linear approximation at the point $X_{01}=(1/2, 1/4, 1/4)$ and its characteristic polynomial:

```
   J01 = FullSimplify[J /. X01];
polJ01 = -Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[J01, λ], λ, FullSimplify]
(*polJ0 = A0 λ^3 + A1 λ^2 + A2 λ^1 + A3;
  A0 = 1; A1 = (8 (66748 + 9580565 ε))/(25302915 ε); 
  A2 = (4 (268141961 + 2208997920 ε))/(7514965755 ε);
  A3 = 571980408512/(743981609745 ε) *)
```

According to the Routh-Hurwitz criterion, $X_{01}$ is stable if and only if

```
Reduce[A1 > 0 && A2 > 0 && A3 > 0 && A1 A2 - A3 > 0 && ε > 0]
(*0 < ε < (239125592953 - Sqrt[31922603976781931264305])/5465060854080 || 
      ε > (239125592953 + Sqrt[31922603976781931264305])/5465060854080*)
```

The last result means that we have two critical Hopf values for $\varepsilon$ at point $X_{01}$. According to the Liu criterion for the Hopf bifurcation, these critical values are calculated as follows

```
ε0 = Solve[A1 A2 - A3 == 0 && ε > 0, ε]];
(*{{ε -> (239125592953 - Sqrt[31922603976781931264305])/5465060854080}, 
   {ε -> (239125592953 + Sqrt[31922603976781931264305])/5465060854080}}*)
```

At the other equilibrium points, the analysis is similar, except for the second equilibrium, since it is unstable.